# BDD Style UI testing for Compact.Net Forms

Tags: compact-framework, bdd, gui-testing

I am used to using Cucumber or StoryQ with Selenium/Webdriver (based upon my platform) for automated UI testing in a continous integration environment, I have looked at White for winforms testing before now however the problem I am facing is that my next project is targetting Compact.Net and I would like to continue testing in this manner.

So could anyone recommend any tool which would be akin to Selenium or White, but support Compact.Net UIs. Ideally I would like to use StoryQ and write the tests in C# for this one as there will be more developers than testers.

One thing that I cannot get my head around 100% is that the forms are hosted on the device/emulator, so I am assuming if anything *can* do what im asking it would require the build server to have an emulator running on it to carry out these tests.

Comment: There isnt a tool to do what I want really, there are some commerical apps that allow you to do *some* of what I was after but its no where near as simple as I had hoped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some discussion of this in [Automated GUI Testing .NET CF (Windows Mobile 5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394141/automated-gui-testing-net-cf-windows-mobile-5).  Whatever tool you use will have to run inside the emulator as well.

Comment: Yeah seen this one, but it didnt come out with any conclusive answers and is about 2 years old. Just wanted to see if anything new had come on the scene... I doubt it thought as compact.net is dead and buried now...